# SSH using yaml via jumphost

Tags: ssh, yaml, github-actions

is there a way that i can SSH to VM using yaml by using Jumphost?

The action will be like.

github(action) -> ssh user@ip (jumphost) -> ssh user@ip (prod server)

Answer (score 0):

Add this action https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ssh-command on your workflow then write your scripts in the `command` option.

Comment: It works. But I have to whitelist from all IP before it can reach my jumphost server. Any idea what is the specific IP?